# Pedir 2 valores y sacar el producto sólo sumando

Tags: bash, shell-script

quiero sacar el producto (es decir, la multiplicación, pero sólo haciendo sumas sucesivas).

Hasta ahora tengo este código.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Introduce un dato"
read A
echo "Introduce el segundo dato"
read B
for (( C=1; C<$B; C++ ))
      do
            C=`expr $C + $B`
            echo "El producto es: $C"
done
```

No sé si sería necesario hacer otro bucle, también había pensado en si se podía aumentar en el FOR un valor, me explico, sé que se pueden incrementar las variables con ++, pero esto es posible de hacer poniéndole otra variable¿?. Para que así tal vez si se pudiese hacer las sumas sucesivas. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el operador `+=` para incrementar, además que puedes hacer esto dentro del doble paréntesis ( `(( expresion ))` ) que es semejante a `expr` (sólo que tengo entendido que este último es arcaico).

Tu código podría quedar de esta manera:

```
#!/bin/bash

resultado=0

echo "Introduce un dato:"
read factor1

echo "Introduce el segundo dato:"
read factor2

for (( i=1; i <= factor2; i++ ))
do
    ((resultado+=factor1))
done

echo resultado: "$resultado"
```

Resultando su ejecución:

```
$ ./multiplicacion.sh
Introduce un dato:
10
Introduce el segundo dato:
11
resultado: 110
```

Comment: También puedes decir `read -p "Introduce un dato: " factor1` para evitarte el `echo`. Por lo demás, el último `echo` sería bueno que lo pusieras entre doble comilla, para coger la práctica.

Comment: @fedorqui Olvide agradecerte por la sugerencia. Buena idea lo de `read -p`, sólo que quería dejar eso como lo puso el que preguntaba (aunque la verdad, yo ya lo estaba olvidando).